# How to use multiple Stripe API keys in Djstripe webhook, is it even possible?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my mind around this issue - is it possible to somehow use more than just one Stripe API key in Djstripe webhook handler? If so, how?

I have two client apps, both using Stripe. Expectedly, there are two sets of Stripe API keys, each set for a client app. There are no issues with making the payment intents and charging, app is sending enough info, and the keys are explicitly defined (e.g. `stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`) so those part of the code can juggle between API keys succesfully.

The hard problem I have encountered is, Stripe webhook handler does not have info to do the juggling - it fails with an error saying:

`stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request <req_id>: No such payment_intent: <payment_intent_id>`

Sure enough, if I use only one set of API keys, it'll do as expected, but I'd need them both.

My idea is to use two webhook endpoints, but I'm not sure how to define additional webhook endpoint in my `config/urls.py` file. Currently, I'm using this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),
    ...
```

In the `webhook.py` file, I'm using `@webhooks` decorator:

```
@webhooks.handler('payment_intent.succeeded')
def payment_intent_succeeded(event, **kwargs):
    # code goes here...
```

Since there are only two sets of API keys, I can try to use one key in `try` block, then use another if that one fails, but there is some magic configuration string usage there I was not able to crack, code inside that webhook never gets executed, so I can't even try that approach.
I was wondering is there any way to define what API key to use there?

Thank you for any ideas!

(I'm using `dj-stripe` version `2.5.1`, and yes, I've inherited that code)

Comment: I am not familiar with dj-stripe but their Changelog indicates that they added support for multiple API keys in 2.6.0 https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/releases/tag/2.6.0

Comment: Also found this doc on actually adding the keys in the admin page https://dj-stripe.dev/api_keys/